# How to avoid parent view/viewgroup animation for click events in GridView's cell

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview, android-gridlayout

I am using a TextView inside a LinearLayout for GridView's cell. The TextView is supposed to animate(like button) in pressed state, for which I am using drawable property. Everything is fine apart from the fact that the rectangular Grid cell gets little darken even outside circle, which i wasn't expecting. This is shown in the image below.

[image]

Question: What is it called and How to avoid it?

The XML resources are as follows:

- Layout used for grid cell

  ```
  <TextView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:id="@+id/id_gridCell"
      android:background="@drawable/circularbutton_selector"
      android:layout_margin="0dp"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
      android:textSize="40dp"
      android:text="-"
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
      android:elevation="5dp"
      />
  ```
- circularbutton_selector.xml

  ```
  <item android:state_selected="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/circularbutton_selected"/>
  <item android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/circularbutton_pressed"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/circularbutton"/>
  ```
- circularbutton_pressed

  ```
  <solid android:color="@color/accent_material_light"/>
  <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#AAA"/>
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that should be the `listSelector` property of `GridView` and `ListView`. Add

```
android:listSelector="#00000000"
```

or

```
   android:listSelector="@null"
```

to the `xml` of your `<GridView`

Comment: Just wanted to understand is the catch here to set alpha to zero here?

Comment: Yes it is. You could also use  `android:color/transparent`